# Multi-threading in Ruby (MRI)

Tags: ruby, multithreading

According to GIL implementation in Ruby (MRI), the code below must fail by printing a message more than one time. But it doesn't, it always print it one time:

```
class Sheep
  def initialize
    @shorn = false
  end

  def shorn?
    @shorn
  end

  def shorn!
    puts "shearing..."
    @shorn = true
  end
end

s = Sheep.new
55.times.map do
  Thread.new { s.shorn! unless s.shorn? }
end.each(&:join)
```

How come?

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends a bit on which exact ruby version you use (which differ in the way they schedule threads). On my system it depends a bit on the overall system load and how fast the terminal feels, but on Ruby 2.0.00p481 I get between 1 and 55 lines of output, on Ruby 1.8.7, I consistently get only one line.

It should be noted here that Ruby 2.0 and higher uses actual OS threads (albeit still with a GIL) while Ruby 1.8 uses internal green threads with its own scheduling. It might be very well possible that older ruby versions schedule threads more granular.

In any case, you should not rely on any incidentally thread scheduling behavior. This is not part of any documented behavior and things **will** change on different systems as as Ruby matures. You should always ensure that you use shared data structures safely when using threads.

Comment: Where is the proof that Ruby 2.0 uses OS threads? I use Ruby 2.0 but always have one printed message.

Comment: Even so it's native OS threads, MRI Ruby can NOT execute more than thread at the same time, can it?

Comment: Exactly, while Ruby 2.0 uses OS threads, it still has its GIL ([global interpreter lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock)) which ensures that only one thread can run at a time. Note that there are other Ruby implementation, most prominently JRuby and Rubinius, which offer true parallelism, i.e. the ability to run multiple threads in parallel (on a multi-CPU box) without a GIL. As for the "proof" that Ruby 1.9 and newer uses native threads, please refer to [this](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/08/14/threads-in-ruby-enough-already/) blog post by Yehuda Katz.

Answer (score 0):

I use Ruby version `ruby 2.1.5p273` and I suppose your slightly different Ruby version should yield similar results.

I have different results every time I run the program.

I tried with one core enabled and fore cores enabled. I don't see a difference. It is not thread safe, as you expected.

Otherwise the only answer I can come up with is that your program is too fast/lightweight, so that the interpreter does not think of thread switching too often.

I have only one suggestion in this case. A trick you could use to give the interpreter a hint that maybe she could switch threads. You could use the `sleep` function.

In your example I would put it just before the `race condition`:

```
  def shorn!
    sleep 0.0001
    puts "shearing..."
    @shorn = true
  end
```

If you'd like to have more info about the GIL I can recommend Jesse Storimer's [Nobody understands the GIL](http://www.jstorimer.com/blogs/workingwithcode/8085491-nobody-understands-the-gil)

If you'd like to read more about Ruby and concurrency I can recommend Dotan Nahum's [Pragmatic Concurrency with Ruby](http://blog.paracode.com/2012/09/07/pragmatic-concurrency-with-ruby/)

The trick I suggested was mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18576777/1566187)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the GIL's behavior is not documented and is totally implementation-dependent. You shouldn't rely on any expectations about its scheduling behavior.

A more detailed (and also more general) answer, however, is that the scheduler switches execution between threads to make sure that no single thread blocks the process. This switch is called a *context switch* or more specifically a *thread switch*.

When the context switch occurs, the current thread's execution is paused and another thread's execution is resumed. If it's a brand new thread that's being "resumed," then it means that the new thread's execution starts from the beginning.

In the case of your program, each new thread begins with

```ruby
s.shorn?
```

as it evaluates `unless s.shorn?`. At this point, `@shorn == false` and `s.shorn?` evaluates to false. So then the thread runs:

```ruby
s.shorn!
```

The first command in `#shorn!` that gets run is:

```ruby
puts "shearing..."
```

What happens next depends on the thread scheduler:

1. If the scheduler decides to let the current thread continue executing, then the next command that gets executed is `@shorn = true`. Then the thread ends, the scheduler starts the next thread, `unless s.shorn?` evaluates to true, and the thread stops. This behavior repeats in a loop until there are no more threads left.
2. If the scheduler decides to switch to another thread, then it will pause execution right before `@shorn = true` and start running the same code as before from the beginning. *That means that `@shorn == false` when the new thread starts*, and so `puts "shearing..."` will execute again.

As you can see, it all depends on when the scheduler decides to perform a context switch.

### But what about the GIL?

The GIL is a horribly misunderstood part of MRI Ruby. There are plenty of resources out there to explain how the GIL works, but in this case the most important thing that you should know is that the GIL doesn't guarantee that each thread will run sequentially.

Instead, the GIL merely guarantees that most core Ruby methods that are implemented in C (for example, `Array#<<`) won't be interrupted by a context switch until they are finished. In the case of `puts "shearing..."`, I haven't looked at the code for `puts`, but probably the GIL guarantees that no other thread will run until the currently running thread finishes executing `puts`.

As for why when you ran your code under MRI 1.8.7 it only displayed `shearing...` once, that doesn't necessarily have anything to do with green vs. native threads. The better answer is that it was a coincidence. The more precise answer is that in your case, for some reason the scheduler decided to interrupt the first thread after running `@shorn = true`. This behavior may possibly have been due to green threads in the sense that maybe your native scheduler interrupts more frequently than Ruby's scheduler (hence the "more granular" suggestion in one of the answers below), but that's not necessarily true. It could also have been a fluke.

Multithreading in Ruby is really easy to mess up. Hence why Matz recommends sticking to forking processes, which is memory-inefficient but removes the burden of managing threads. Another approach for larger projects would be to use a library like [Celluloid](https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid), which abstracts away Ruby's thread safety mechanisms. For a small example like this, however, a simple mutex would do:

```ruby
semaphore = Mutex.new

s = Sheep.new
55.times.map {
  Thread.new {
    semaphore.synchronize do
      s.shorn! unless s.shorn?
    end
  }
}.each(&:join)
```